# PeeWee + SQLite3 on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bottle, peewee

I'm trying to use **Google App Engine** to deploy a **BootlePy + PeeWee** web application.

I use **PeeWee** with **SQLite**.

Here is **PeeWee's** source code:

```
try:
    import sqlite3
except ImportError:
    sqlite3 = None
```

Here is the error I'm getting in my **Google App Engine** development console:

```
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

Why does the import fails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google App Engine does not allow sqlite, thus does not have the module within it. Here is a bit more info: [Using sqlite3 within Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150115/using-sqlite3-within-google-app-engine)